Is there a command to point out everywhere the default line spacing is being changed by math formulas?
I would like to ensure that my default line spacing is not being altered to accommodate math formulas and equations, and instead anything that is so big that it will affect the line spacing is put in its own equation environment.
Besides searching 40+ pages by hand for slightly larger-than-normal spaces between lines, is there any kind of package, command, or tool that could be used to detect the lines where the default line spacing is being changed by math formulas?

Add \showoutput to your preamble and then check the log for \lineskip which is added to lines when they are too large to allow \baselineskip spacing.

logs
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 c
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 c
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 c
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
...\penalty 150
...\glue(\baselineskip) 3.11111


....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 f
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 x
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 f
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 x
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
...\glue(\lineskip) 1.0


....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 j
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 z
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 j
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 z
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 0.60715


....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 n
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 n
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 n
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
...\penalty 150
...\glue(\baselineskip) 5.75002


showing \baselineskip after the first and fourth  line but \lineskip after the second and third as the math expression is both too tall and too deep to allow \baselineskip space to be used above or below the third line.
